# Why would humans fight a planet full of monsters?

Tags: planets, warfare, modern, creature-design

So in my world a portal suddenly opened on a field. The portal leads to a planet full of monsters. Why would the people in my world attack and defeat the evil planet. What resources would there have to be for there to be strong motivation. This is in a semi-modern world. For example 1800s or 1700s. If it matters the portal was opened by evil magicians.

Comment: If you want to merge new account with old one you mention you had but lost, I think the moderators can help you with that.

Comment: Ok how do I reach the moderators?

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.

Comment: I think that your question is too broad and does not have enough context to give you a proper answer. You provide so little information that **any motivation** for conquest would work.

Comment: Why do you say the planet is evil? What specifically makes the inhabitants monsters? Why humans would invade is easy: free natural resources. In the 18-19th century, the [Doctrine of Discovery](https://www.gilderlehrman.org/history-resources/spotlight-primary-source/doctrine-discovery-1493) was still in force in Europe

Answer (score 8):

**The same old reasons.**

1. Take their loot and bring it home.  Put it up in your city to impress the folks.  Or melt it down and make coins out of it, with your face on them. Maybe a monster on the flip side so people can chuckle because they got their loot taken.
2. Take their land and grow stuff on it.  Sell that stuff, or eat it.  Or sell it to hungry monsters who used to get their food there until you showed up.  Use their payments for reason #1.
3. Take the monstery people and make them work for you.  They can build a triumphal arch in your city depicting you showing up and taking their stuff.  Once that is done you can have them do other jobs you need doing.
4. Convert their monstery people to your religion.  This is compatible with points 1 thru 3.
5. Kill their monstery people because they came thru the portal to your world with #1,2,3 or 4 in mind.

Comment: nice and funny. i like it

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps for ownership of land. During those times land represented money, in a way, and I can easily imagine the more ambitious people embarking on that quest to defeat the monsters on the planet. Also, the planet might be useful for research purposes in astronomy.

Comment: I used to have a few thousand reputation but lost the account so now I am a new contributor like you.

Comment: Welcome to the site, I hope you enjoy it! This is a great answer, but generally 1-2 line answers don't get too many votes, so you may want to add other reasons or perhaps add more of your reasoning for a clearer, more thorough explanation. Hope it helps!

Comment: In 1700s, the land itself (particularly, frontier land) was hardly valuable in the New World. However, there were people who just couldn't bear it in the Old World and they were willing to take the risk and move to the other continent.

Comment: When responding to questions it's best to try and keep opinion out of it and fully answer the question. And while responses don't have to be lengthy, it's good to put in examples.

Answer (score 1):

If the monsters happen to resemble abominations from any of the major religious texts, then the portal might be mistaken for a gateway to the darker half of the afterlife.  With such a mistaken conviction, the living heirs of less than saintly loved-ones might invade hell in hopes of liberating their recently damned deceased.  Monsters who happen to die during that liberation would just be collateral damage.